# How to set communication between webview and angular code in a mobile app

Tags: android, angular, typescript, webview, nativescript

Below is Javascript code which run on WebView to gets the userId and TokenValue, I want to get this value in my nativescript app. Wanted to send data from Webview to Nativescript code without using any plugin

```html
['zul.utl.Script','pW7P4',{content:function(){

   (function () {
   try {
   Mobile.saveToken(jq("$userIdLabel").text(), jq("$tokenLabel").text());
   } catch (err) {}
   try {
   var message = {'userId':jq("$userIdLabel").text(), 'token':jq("$tokenLabel").text()};
   window.webkit.messageHandlers.tokenResult.postMessage(message);
   } catch (err) {}
   }());
  
}},[]],
```

Comment: The code you have above is specifically for Android. So yes, you would need iOS specific code if the features / functionalities are applicable. Basically NativeScript Core Modules / all or most plugins create the common JavaScript interface for you to access the native components. For example when you use Label, it runs iOS specific code to handle UILabel and Android specific code to handle TextView on respective platforms. So if you are looking for anything that doesn't come out of the box, yes you must be little familiar with how these native APIs work.

Comment: Also the code above is in Java, you will have to marshall it in JavaScript / TypeScript to use it in your project, override settings from default WebView. Read more about [Java to JS here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/overview)

Comment: @Manoj Hi Manoj, Thanks for your quick reply. But I am working on Nativescript Angular project and I have to implement this code in nativescript, don't know how to set these setting in nativescript even the link you have shared doesn't define how to implement these changes for WebView in nativescript.

Comment: The links do not give you exact code. You got to take one step at a time, you have to learn how to marshall Java to JS first, then learn how plugins / core modules work and then try to override them. [Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=CndpgD&v=92) is a playground sample, that demonstrate how you can change default web view client to chrome client. In your code you have a JavaScript Interface for WebView, I have no clue why it's there or what it would do. Without knowing the exact requirement it's hard to help you with further directions.

Comment: @Manoj : main requirement is I have to open WebView in mobile app where user will login and then I have to get that username and password in mobile, So to set an interaction between mobile app and web page there is a use of webClient by enabling Javascript, So that backend can get to know request is coming from "Mobile" and on successful login they have to send back username value.

Basically I have to set communication between webview and angular code in a mobile app

Comment: Sorry, it's not very clear yet. Do you want to intercept the login when user clicks on the login button Or want to read the access token or something upon successful login?

Comment: @Manoj Okay so the flow is User click on login webView will be open where user enter login credentials and on successful login on WebView, token and username will be sent to activity from WebView.

Comment: Ok, in that case I don't think you need all the above. Can you confirm whether your token, username etc., stored in local / session storage upon successful login?

Comment: @Manoj token and username is coming from backend on WebView and I want to set communication between WebView and activity, so that once I can get the token in activity and save it mobile local database.

Comment: I get that is coming form backend, I'm trying to ask in what form it's coming, whether as a cookie / saved to local / session storage by web app / sometimes it will be the redirect URL. So which format is yours?

Comment: @Manoj its saved to local, this link is an exact implementation I want in Angular instead of Android : https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#UsingJavaScript

Comment: @Manoj I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess you meant local storage by "local", to enable local storage on your Android WebView, you have to call 2 methods upon loaded event - [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=DbiXe8&v=1). Once logged in (you could probably listen to loadFinished event), you may use evaluateJavaScript method to run JS code within web app context to read the data from local storage.

Comment: [Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=FuYuXe&v=2) is an example of running evaluateJavaScript but it injects CSS into web app, basically you need to pass the code to read and return your local storage data.

Comment: @Manoj : Thank You so much, I will try, this is what I needed. Really Appreciate you help, Thanks :)

Comment: @Manoj : Your given examples dint worked. I have added more details if you can help.

Comment: Share a complete Playground sample of issue. The link looks good on my end.

Comment: @Manoj : you code is working, but it is not sending token value back on my native code.

Comment: above scripting Code is of Web, on successful login on web the scripts run and Mobile.save and message handle method returns the token value which I need to get in my code from WebView.